# What's the right article for "Issue" in German?

Tags: article, loanword, software, english

In software development and **IT** slang, it is very common to **adapt English expressions to German** language.

Beispiele:

> Ein *Bug* ist ein Programmierfehler.
> Ein *Commit* ist ein eingesandter Beitrag eines Programmierers.
>
> **Ein/eine Issue** ist ein Problem bzw. Streitpunkt oder eine Angelegenheit, die es im Rahmen zukünftiger Bemühungen zu adressieren gilt.

Aber was ist der korrekte Artikel? / **What's the correct article in German?**

Comment: Gefühlsmäßig am ehesten "das Issue", aber es gibt recht wenige schriftliche Belege dazu. "Das", weil es meistens ein Problem (sächlich) referenziert.

Comment: Vielleicht nimmst Du doch besser einen deutschen Begriff, wenn Du Dir mit dem Artikel einen abbrechen musst...

Comment: [Hier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issue_Management#Issues) heißt es "Das Issue..."). Ich bin mir aber nciht sicher, ob es das gleiche bedeutet wie in der Frage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use "das" for Github issues and haven't heard the use of any other article for it.

Avoiding the word "issue" seems like a poor solution because this term is used a lot in IT and is specific to Github issues if the entire conversation is about a project on Github. "Issue" then doesn't refer to issues in general.

It very often is the case that the German article for the closest translation is used. "Issue" matches closely to "Problem" as well as to "Thema". Both of which are neutral. So it seems natural to go with "das" and that's exactly what's happening.

This does, however, not always work. Another example for common usage of English words in German IT context is "interface". The German translation is "Schnittstelle" which is female ("die"). The German article for "interface", however, is "das" (neutral). Maybe that's because "face" (Ger.: "Gesicht") is neutral. But sometimes the articles people go with don't make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 7):

Duden knows only a "**das** Reissue" - for "Wiederausgabe" of records or books. (Even if "Ausgabe" is feminine) This hints to neuter.

*Issue* in my daily usage would directly translate to "Problem", which is clearly neuter. I do not really see an *issue* with simply using "Problem". In my usage it is a problem someone had with your software which might or might not be accepted as (and thus evolving) into a bug or malfunction.

So, if you think you absolutely **must** use *issue*, "das Issue" would be correct.

Comment: Wieso ist Problem eher passend als Angelegenheit oder Punkt? Welche Regel besagt, dass ein Fremdwort den Artikel der dt. Übersetzung bekommt? Der Song (das Lied), die E-Mail (der elektronische Brief), der Shop (das Geschäft).

Comment: @userunknown: Die von tofro genannte Regel halte ich für nahe liegend, auch wenn sie nirgendwo fixiert ist. Da wir nicht in der Mathematik sind, ist die Aussagekraft von einzelnen Gegenbeispielen ohne eine quantitative Analyse überschaubar.

Comment: @guidot Diese „Regel“ zählt auch nicht zu den von Duden genannten kritieren (http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/Duden_Das_Fremdwort_Lesenswertes_und_Interessantes.pdf Seite 5) und halte ich persönlich auch eher für einen Irrglauben.

Comment: Dann möchtest du dein verlinktes Dokument nochmal lesen-da steht sehr deutlich "...nach dem Geschlecht möglicher deutscher Entsprechungen... " und als Beispiel wird die "E-post" genannt